# Angular 7, How to add Single loader for multiple HTTP calls

Tags: http, angular7, loader

I am working on Angular7, I created one extremely big component (ComponentA) which includes 8 child components, Each child component have their own DATA calls (HTTP calls)

My client wants the loader or spinner while Parent component(ComponentA) loading, And ends the loader once all the 8 child components data gets retrieved(HTTP requests success).

Expected Result for each component:

The loader Should strats when the first API call starts, It should end when the last API call completed

I am using HTTP interceptors

Comment: You can create a global variable and after each data call from child component. So you check global variable or array with 8 dataname. If the global varible has 8 data name then stop the loader else keep showing.

Comment: Okay Thanks, Santosh, how to pass the global variable to parent component from all child components

Comment: That is only the flow. You need to figure out how you can access the array that is created in parent component to child component in Angular.